# Why does my windows explorer not show thumbnails?

Tags: windows-vista, windows-explorer, thumbnails

When I used to open a file with photos I used to get very useful thumbnails, now I only get icons. How do I change it back?

I have checked the file properties and it is set to Photos and movies...

Answer (score 3):

Open any folder in windows go to extra/organise, click `"Folder Options"`. Under the `"Files and Folders"` tab, uncheck the box next to `"Always show icons, never thumbnails"`.

Click the OK or apply button.